# Autofac - InstancePerLifetimeScope vs InstancePerRequest in Application_Start in ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: autofac

I am using Autofac With ASP.NET Webforms. I would like to understand the difference between InstancePerLifetimeScope and InstancePerRequest when i register dependencies in the App_Start method of the global.asx.

It look like that for both of them a new instance of the dependency is created just once at Every HttpRequest (verified with a breakpoint into the constructor of the dependency and with the HashCode of the object).

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Travis gave good link to the documentation describing how it works. However, I prefer to give examples additionally to illustrate the theory better. So, let's take a look at simple example.

Suppose you have two classes ClassA and ClassB implementing some simple interfaces IClassA and IClassB.

```
public class ClassA : IClassA
{
    public ClassA() {
    }
}

public class ClassB : IClassB
{
    public ClassB() {
    }
}
```

Now, let's see what happens when we register them in different ways.

**Example A**

```
builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<ClassA>().As<IClassA>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();    
builder.RegisterType<ClassB>().As<IClassB>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Then, in the controller, you do this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IClassA _classA;
    private readonly IClassB _classB;
    private readonly IComponentContext _ctx;

    public HomeController(IClassA classA, IClassB classB, IComponentContext ctx) {
        _classA = classA;
        _classB = classB;
        _ctx = ctx;
    }

    public string Get() {
        using (var scope = _ctx.BeginLifetimeScope()) {
            var newClassA = scope.Resolve<IClassA>(); // Object.ReferenceEquals(newClassA, _classA) == false
            var newClassB = scope.Resolve<IClassB>(); // Object.ReferenceEquals(newClassB, _classB) == false
            return "Ok";
        }
    }
}
```

In this example both 'new' variables in Get() method will receive new instances since they are both registered to be unique **per lifetime scope**. We began new lifetime scope - we got new instances.

Now, let's take a look at another example.

**Example B**

```
builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<ClassA>().As<IClassA>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<ClassB>().As<IClassB>().InstancePerRequest(); // now they have different life time!

// controller:

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IClassA _classA;
    private readonly IClassB _classB;
    private readonly IComponentContext _ctx;

    public HomeController(IClassA classA, IClassB classB, IComponentContext ctx) {
        _classA = classA;
        _classB = classB;
        _ctx = ctx;
    }

    public string Get() {
        using (var scope = _ctx.BeginLifetimeScope()) {
            var newClassA = scope.Resolve<IClassA>(); // Object.ReferenceEquals(newClassA, _classA) == false
            var newClassB = scope.Resolve<IClassB>(); // Object.ReferenceEquals(newClassB, _classB) == true
            return "Ok";
        }
    }

}
```

See what happened here? Even though we began new lifetime scope - ClassB still gets resolved from request scope and not from our new one. This is the difference between InstancePerLifetimeScope() and InstancePerRequest().

And as documentation suggests, internally it is based on another Autofac concept - [InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope()](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/working-with-scopes.html#tagging-a-lifetime-scope).

Answer (score 3):

In many cases it amounts to the same thing. [This is an FAQ on the Autofac doc site.](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html#sharing-dependencies-across-apps-without-requests)